# módulos javascript (trabajar 100% desde consola)

Tags: javascript, consola, modulos

¡Hola querida comunidad!

Intento trabajar con módulos en JavaScript:

Tengo dos archivos **index1.js** e **index2.js**
En **index2.js** defino una función que quiero *exportar* para *importar* desde index1.js.

La idea es ejecutar con `node index1.js` y que funcione el código que reuso desde index2.js.

Les cuento el **setup** que hice:

```
lib/
   index1.js
   index2.js
src/
   index1.js
   index2.js
babel.config.json
package.json
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "jsmodule",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "JavaScript modules - ECMAScript modules",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "npx babel src -w --out-dir lib"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "js",
    "modules"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0"
  }
}
```

babel.config.json

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

src/index1.js

```
import fn2 from './index2.js';

console.log(fn2());
```

src/index2.js

```
export default function fn2() {
    return 'Soy una función del módulo 2.'
}
```

Pero no hay forma de hacerlo andar... Me larga distintos errores cuando ejecuto `node lib/index1.js`

```
PS C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\jsmodule> node lib/index1.js
(node:25828) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///C:/Users/.../Documents/GitHub/jsmodule/lib/index1.js:3
var _index = _interopRequireDefault(require("./index2.js"));
             ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///C:/Users/.../Documents/GitHub/jsmodule/lib/index1.js:3:14
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:139:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
```

Comment: Mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723678/node-experimental-modules-error-cannot-find-module), te puede ser útil.